# Do I need to Replace this Tire if Switching Back to Tubes?

Tags: tubeless

I am new to cycling and asked the local bike shop to set up my bike tubeless.

It's a second hand scott speedster. My rear tire had a puncture that I never noticed when riding with tubes, but originally prevented the tire from sealing in the bike shop. They eventually got it to work but on the first ride, I had a flat/slow leak that sprayed sealant up the frame.

Since then I added a dynaplug and after the first ride, I could see bubbles and sealant at the point of puncture.

I let it sit overnight and I can still see a small spec of sealant after a 5km test ride.

My question is:

1. Can I still use this tire if I remove the dynaplug and go back to Tubes?
2. Should I get a new tire?

I am a bigger rider (260lbs) - training for a Fondo and like to ride on light trail gravel plus roads.

Comment: Great first question - welcome to the site !   What size tyres are they?  And what air pressure do you run them ?

Comment: And also what make/model of tyre is it, and what type of sealant did the bike shop use?  It sounds like they used a brand of sealant that doesnt work well at high pressure.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can still use that tire with a tube. I don't think you want to remove the dynaplug, but you do want to cut off the "bullet" on the inside.

Comment: whats a bullet?

Comment: [this](http://www.dynaplug.com/clearbox/large/soft_nose.jpg) is what dynaplug plugs look like. The bullet goes inside the tire.

Comment: I endorse this answer. FYI, the brass tip (i.e. the bullet) can be pulled or twisted off the rest of the plug by hand if you don't have scissors or a knife on you.